# How to hide a post from archives

Tags: archives

I want to hide the WordPress post from archives page using the 'private' option. I only want the post to be hidden from archives but visible to public. How to I do it?

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to filter the main query via `pre_get_posts` callback.

If you'll only want to handle one specific post in this manner, you can reference/exclude its post ID directly. If, however, you want this same behavior for any future private posts, then I would query all posts with `$post->post_status` of `private`, and exclude them.

One post (where ID = 123):

```
function wpse99672_filter_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_singular() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post__not_in', array( 123 ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse99672_filter_pre_get_posts' );
```

Or, for all `private` posts:

```
function wpse99672_filter_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_singular() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        // Query all post objects for private posts
        $private_posts = new WP_Query( array( 'post_status' => 'private' ) );
        // Extract post IDs
        // Note: for performance, you could consider
        // adding this array to a transient
        $private_post_ids = array();
        foreach ( $private_posts as $obj ) {
            $private_post_ids[] = $obj->ID;
        }
        $query->set( 'post__not_in', $private_post_ids );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse99672_filter_pre_get_posts' );
```

Comment: Finally I found something - Thank you. With this, together with a custom post status, you can hide old posts from the archive, but keep the SEO value and also be able to read the post. - been looking for this for about an hour.

Answer (score -1):

I think the easiest way would be to control the loop in the `archive.php` file, IF it's just the one post you want to hide from the archives.

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'p=-7' );
```

Where 7 is the post_ID of the post you want to hide and the `-` sign designates you want to exclude it from the loop.

Take a look at [this link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) that explains the usage and arguments that can be passed, in case you want to go further then what your question suggests.

[Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) and [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts) you can find alternate methods to accomplish what I mentioned.

**--- Update ---**

Given toscho's comments I've [dug around a bit](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) and here is how you can use a filter on the `pre_get_posts()`:

```
function exclude_post( $query ) {
    if ( is_archive() ) {
        $query->set( 'p', -7 );
        return;
    }//end if
}//end function
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_post' );
```

Comment: A new `WP_Query` just to hide one post? Why would you waste the original query?

Comment: I did take a peek at the `get_posts();` arguments and I didn't find the `$post_ID` so I mentioned the last 2 links for clarification without going into it again.

Would something like this be better?

`<?php if(is_archive()) {
$args = array( 'post_ID' => -7 );
$show_posts = get_posts ( $args );
}
?>`

Comment: A filter on `pre_get_posts` is the only fast option here in my opinion.

Comment: Not sure about `if ( is_archive() )` or `if ($query->is_archive)`. Both usages are in different examples on the codex.